# PHP encoding issues with quotes (“„) and other special characters

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, internationalization

I've a problem with encoding on german website.
I have a text:

> „Eröffnungsfeier FIS Alpine Ski WM 2011“

When this text is saved into database I get ? instead of those quotes.

I've tried placing

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf-8');
```

On the top of the file without success.

When I've used

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connect);
```

But then, when inserting text above after reaching first character like ö the rest of the text is stripped.

The table charset and collation is UTF-8.
Script file is saved as UTF-8 without BOM.

I lack of ideas where to look.

Comment: Seems you did it well. Could you provide a link to the page? Did you set a http-equiv meta tag other than utf-8? I would check the page that inserts the text into the database.

Comment: Do you publish on a self-administered web server? Maybe you forgot to generate the locale in cause here (edit `/etc/locales.gen`, uncomment whatever you want, then `locale-gen` as root), it happened to me many times :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things I did helped. Especially `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connect);`.
The problem was that there was some unwanted code left by another programmer (utf8_decode).
Looks like he couldn't deal with utf-8 encoding other way.

I've also found out that `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connect);` is not really needed if you're consistent with the encoding from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check the schema of your database - are the text fields set up to store utf-8?

2) It sounds like the page *posting* to this script is not sending UTF-8. Does it have the correct `Content-Type` header? What does `echo urlencode($var)` show? (that's a neat hack to see the raw bytes you're getting)

Comment: The table charset is UTF8. Fileds have collation of utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Updated answer with another possible solution